# How to only get the data of the nested JSON object MongoDB with node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON object in my MONGODB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9848621854d8fb2b1e1"),
"Bot_name" : "Scheduling bot",
"Modules" : [ 
    {
        "ModuleID" : "1111",
        "ModuleStatement" : "This is a Sceduling bot, Would you like to book a flight?",
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9968621854d8fb2b1e3"),
        "ModuleResponse" : [ 
            {
                "Response" : "yes",
                "TransBotID" : "1112"
            }, 
            {
                "Response" : "no",
                "TransBotID" : "1113"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "ModuleID" : "1112",
        "ModuleStatement" : "Where would you like to go? New York ? LA?",
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9968621854d8fb2b1e3"),
        "ModuleResponse" : [ 
            {
                "Response" : "New York",
                "TransBotID" : "1121"
            }, 
            {
                "Response" : "LA",
                "TransBotID" : "1122"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "ModuleID" : "1121",
        "ModuleStatement" : " New York..",
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9968621854d8fb2b1e3"),
        "ModuleResponse" : []
    }, 
     {
        "ModuleID" : "1121",
        "ModuleStatement" : " New York..",
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9968621854d8fb2b1e3"),
        "ModuleResponse" : []
      }
   }
```

Im making a query that will first check the Bot_name and then check the ModuleID which is in the nested array Modules containing JSON object which are 1111, 1112 , 1121 .. so on 
how do i only get the json object of `ModuleID:1111` of `Bot_name:Scheduling bot`

so far my query is

```
botSchema.findOne({ Bot_name: req.body.Name ,'Modules.ModuleID':req.body.MID}, function (err, data) {
console.log(data)
   }
```

here the query returns all the json inside the `Modules`

how to only get one desired json object? like this

```
{
    "ModuleID" : "1111",
    "ModuleStatement" : "This is a Sceduling bot, Would you like to book a flight?",
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9968621854d8fb2b1e3"),
    "ModuleResponse" : [ 
        {
            "Response" : "yes",
            "TransBotID" : "1112"
        }, 
        {
            "Response" : "no",
            "TransBotID" : "1113"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your query (`'Modules.ModuleID: req.body.MID`) should be working and filtering the `Modules` array. So technically `data.Modules[0]` should be what you want.

Comment: doesn't work . it returns all the Modules json object

Comment: it works if i use for loops but it would be easier to query and get the exact json i want . is that possible or we can only get all of the object as my schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$elemMatch` for filter sub arrays.

```
db.botSchema.findOne( 
    { Bot_name: "Scheduling bot"} 
    , { 'Modules': { $elemMatch:{'ModuleID':"1111"} } }
    , function (err, data) { console.log(data) })
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9848621854d8fb2b1e1"),
    "Modules" : [ 
        {
            "ModuleID" : "1111",
            "ModuleStatement" : "This is a Sceduling bot, Would you like to book a flight?",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b9968621854d8fb2b1e3"),
            "ModuleResponse" : [ 
                {
                    "Response" : "yes",
                    "TransBotID" : "1112"
                }, 
                {
                    "Response" : "no",
                    "TransBotID" : "1113"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```